# Android Studio code style

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

how do i change the code style so that `Reformat code` doesn't remove my line breaks in this case:

```
DrawerItemInterface[] menu = new DrawerItemInterface[] {
    DrawerHeaderItem.create(100, "Header"),
    DrawerItem.create(101, "Item", false, getActivity())
};
```

Executing `Reformat code` gives me this junk:

```
DrawerItemInterface[] menu = new DrawerItemInterface[]{DrawerHeaderItem.create(100, "Header"), DrawerItem.create(101, "Item", false, getActivity())};
```

Comment: I don't know Android Studio specifically but in IntelliJ (which it's based on) "Code Style" is at the top of the settings dialog (File, Settings on Windows). You probably want Java, 'Blank Lines' tab.

Comment: @Rup I know where the settings are, but not which one to change to affect this code.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings-> Code Style -> Java then in the right side, check the **Line breaks**. Then it should work as you expected

[image]

Comment: Is there another way except for this setting? I want it to remove other line breaks.